# Angularjs hide and show according to screen size responsive

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, responsive-design

Hi every one I am trying to achieve this

[image]

When the user is on desktop, he should see the block when he visits the page, and the user should see the button when he is on mobile and then he should be able to toggle it.

I am able to show the button using CSS media query by setting 
    **display: none** when screen size is <480px and also able to revert the 
    **display: none** to **block** by adding **ng-click="showBlocks={'display': 'block'}**

But I am not sure how can i make it work in a sense when I click on it again it should hide the blocks again.

I have tried ng-hide/show but it doesn't work unless i remove **display:none** for the mobile size and when i do remove it then I am not able to see the blocks when visit the page for first time.

Please help me I have wasted so much time on it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have one div that contains the view you want normally and another for mobile. Hide/show them based on screen size. For the mobile, just implement your logic for toggling the block.

Comment: @JeremyJackson I tried but didn't work, as it displays the block on mobile size, when i visit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a code sample it's hard to tell where you are. If you managed to get the button to hide the blocks (like you said with `ng-click="showBlocks={'display': 'block'}`) then adding a variable should be enough. Add this to the button element:

`ng-init="show=true;" ng-click="show = !show; showBlocks={'display': (show?'block':'none')};"`

If that works, then move the initialisation logic to the controller to keep things clean.

Comment: Thanks a ton @chris You're awesome. I was going crazy since yesterday

Comment: Quick question, it's working now but it works after I click twice on the button and afterwards it works with single click

Comment: Not sure what may be causing that. Can you set up a plunker with your code to check what it is you are doing? Could be a bootstrap conflict or some other library.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class on that element which you want to force show if user clicks on the button and use the `!important` flag in the CSS or simply define that rule below the media query to give the higher preference to that CSS class.

Suppose you are adding `force-show` class when user toggles it:

```
.force-show {
    display: block !important
}
```

See an example below. **Use the "Full Page" link to mock the desktop view in the below example**

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope) {

});
```

```css
.block {
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
}
button {
  display: none
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .block {
    display: none;
  }
  button {
    display: block;
  }
}
.force-show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController">
  <div class="block" ng-class="{'force-show': showBlock}">
    I'll only be visible on desktop or using button on mobile.
  </div>

  <button ng-click="showBlock = !showBlock">Toggle blocks
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I am able to show the blocks but I am not able to unblock the button, I mean not sure how to achieve it. I am applying display: block when user clicks on it but not sure how to remove the styling applied on the second click

Comment: Tried this too, but the button doesn't work because of display: none