# Sidenav toggle in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

Can anyone help me with creating toggle button for side navbar in Angular and Typescript

Nav

```
<nav *ngIf="nav.visible" class="sidebar col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 bg-faded sidebar-style-1 sidenav pt-3 mt-1 pr-0 pl-0">
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column sidebar-nav navcss">
  <li class="nav-item"><a routerLink="/home" class="nav-link  h7 pb-2 pr-0" routerLinkActive="active"
                          [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"><em class="fa fa-home mr-2"></em> Home </a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a routerLink="/profile" class="nav-link  h7 pb-2 pr-0"><em class="fa fa-desktop mr-2 "></em> Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a routerLink="/dob" class="nav-link  h7 pb-2 pr-0"><em class="fa fa-calendar-o mr-2"></em><span
    class="sr-only">(current)</span> DOB</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: TypeScript **IS** JavaScript

Comment: vanilla javascript is perfectly valid in typescript, this is not the problem; however, you are using jQuery to select DOM elements in angular, which is far from ideal, use angular functions instead

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

This is the code after conversion to typescript.

(Yes it is the same. But you are clearly asking the wrong question.)

This is how you can show/hide things based on screen size in angular --
[Angularjs hide and show according to screen size responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919796)